# How to find out a decomposition of this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

How to decompose the following: $r^2+rs-r-s $? I know that $(a-b)*(a+b) = a^2-b^2$. I don't know how to fit this to that..

Comment: $(r-1)(r+s)$.  $\quad$

Comment: @pH74 yes, that is what I meant

Answer (score 2):

Make partial factorisations first. Hopefully, the partial factorisations will have a common factor:
$$r^2+rs-r-s=(r^2-r)+(rs-s)=r(r-1)+s(r-1)=(r+s)(r-1).$$

Comment: Thank you, now I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Solve

$$r^2+rs-r-s=0$$ for $s$:

$$s=\frac{r^2-r}{1-r}=-r$$ provided $r\ne1$. So $s+r$ must be a factor. Then if $r=1$, the polynomial vanishes, so $r-1$ must be another factor.

Answer (score 0):

By inspection, the expression cancels when $s=-r$. Hence there must be a factor $r+s$.

Perform the division,

$$r^2+rs-r-s=r(r+s)-r-s=r(r+s)-(r+s)=(r-1)(r+s).$$

---

Note that also by inspection, the expression cancels when $r=1$...

Answer (score 0):

By completing the square,

$$r^2+rs-r-s=\left(r+\frac{s-1}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{s-1}2\right)^2-s=\left(r+\frac{s-1}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{s+1}2\right)^2$$

and you have a difference of squares.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the quadratic equation

$$r^2+r(s-1)-s=0$$ for $r$.

$$r=\dfrac{1-s+\sqrt{(s-1)^2+4s}}2=\frac{1-s\pm(s+1)}{2}=1,-s$$

and

$$r^2+r(s-1)-s\propto(r-1)(r+s).$$

Answer (score 0):

To find the roots of a polynomial $p(x)$ you solve the equation $p(x)=0$ and you get the roots $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. Then the factorization is
$p(x) = (x-x_1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x-x_n)$.

So solve the quadratic equation $r^2 + (s-1) r + (-s) = 0$. The roots are $r_1 = 1$ and $r_2 = -s$. Thus

$$r^2+rs-r-s = (r-1)(r+s).$$

Answer (score 0):

By Vieta, to factor the polynomial in $r$, find two numbers such that their sum is $1-s$ and their product is $-s$. Obviously, $1$ and $-s$, and the factors are $(r-1)$ and $(r+s)$.